# "index out of range" en Go

Tags: go

Manejando `arrays`en Go me doy cuenta que existen dos formas de declararlos.

**Forma 1**

Cuando declaro el array con el tamaño fijo

```
var a [5]int

a[0] = 1
```

Lo anterior no da ningún problema.

**Forma 2**

Cuando declaro el array sin el tamaño.

```
var b []int
```

Lo anterior no da ningún problema, pero cuando intento asignarle un valor, así:

```
b[0] = 1
```

Me aparece este error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range
goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x5fb80, 0xc82000a0a0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
main.main()
    /Users/my/path/main.go:8 +0x38
exit status 2
```

**¿Por qué me aparece ese error?**

Notarán que el mensaje de error es un poco confuso dado que habla de `goroutines`, cosa que no estoy usando todavía (ni sé qué son, sólo sé que existen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En realidad no existen dos formas de declarar un arreglo en `go`, solo hay una forma, y es la primera de las dos que en el ejemplo describe:

```
var a [5]int
```

En go, la longitud del arreglo siempre debe hacer parte de su tipo, esto es debido a que esta estructura de datos en tiempo de ejecución nunca cambiará su tamaño, por lo tanto la sintaxis para declarar un arreglo es:

```
var name [length]T
```

donde length debe ser una constante de tipo `int` no negativa y T es el tipo de dato que contendrá. Evidentemente, una vez creado el arreglo de 5 elementos de tipo `int`, inicializar uno de estos campos es sencillo, de la forma en la que usted lo realizó:

```
a[0] = 1
```

Ahora, en la segunda forma que usted describe no está declarando un arreglo, porque falta la longitud, sino una estructura de datos llamada *slice*. Puede pensar en ella como una estructura que tiene un apuntador a un arreglo y una longitud. Una de varias formas de declarar el slice es como usted lo realiza en la forma dos:

```
var b []int
```

En la instrucción anterior, está declarando un *slice* llamado `b` que apuntará a un arreglo de tipo `int`. Comparando con la sintaxis al declarar un arreglo, si no se especifica el valor de `length`, go asume que usted está creando un *slice*. Ahora, de acuerdo a su ejemplo, usted sólo declaró la variable `b` de tipo `int`, pero ahora debe inicializarla, de lo contrario el valor de esta variable será `nil` (un tipo de dato muy similar a `null` en lenguajes de programación convencionales).

Para inicializar el valor de un *slice* una posible forma es hacer uso de la función `make()`. Esta recibe como parámetro el tipo de dato que desea construir, la longitud inicial de este y un parámetro opcional que indica el valor máximo al que puede ampliar la capacidad del *slice*, como se dará cuenta, esta estructura sí permite ampliar, o disminuir, de forma dinámica la longitud del arreglo. Por lo tanto, a su forma 2 le falta la instrucción:

```
//Construyo un slice de longitud inicial 5 y longitud máxima 10.
b = make([]int, 5, 10)
```

Y ahora sí, puede hacer asignarle valores al *slice*

```
b[0] = 1
```

El error mostrado al ejecutar el código es algo oscuro, porque en realidad detrás de un *slice* siempre habrá un arreglo, ya sea que lo cree con la función `make()` o que lo construya a partir de un arreglo que ya haya creado (como el arreglo `a` en su código). En cualquier caso, de acuerdo a su forma 2, la longitud inicial del *slice* es nil, y al hacer referencia al objeto 0 de este slice, generará un `index out of range` y no un error similar a excepciones como `NullPointerException` en Java, porque en realidad `nil` sólo hace referencia al valor de variables que no se inicializan.

**Sobre la relación con *goroutine***

Una *goroutine* es una función que se ejecuta de forma concurrente al hilo de ejecución principal. Si ha programado en Java puede pensar en que son parecidas al concepto de *Threads*, si no, piense en esto: su programa principal (el hilo de ejecución principal) es su main, o el que ejecuta cuando corre el programa que contiene el código que necesita. Este programa puede "delegar" tareas para que se ejecuten de forma concurrente (al mismo tiempo) que el programa principal. En go, usted logra esto a través de una goroutine. Por su publicación indica que no tiene experiencia en este tema, así que lo invito a buscar más sobre esta hermosa característica de go. Respecto a su duda, cuando el programa encuentra que intenta acceder a un elemento del arreglo que no existe, lanza un error de tipo 'index out of range'. En go, este error genera una llamada a la función panic, que aborta la ejecución del programa. Cuando en su traza indica que el error ocurrió en el goroutine 1 le está indicando en cuál hilo de ejecución se originó este error, pero sólo hay uno sólo: el principal, que es ejecutado siempre como un goroutine a través del método main.go cuando lanza el programa.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me queda la duda aún el por qué aparecen las "goroutines" en el mensaje de error, ¿tienen algo que ver?

Comment: @Gepser, añadí la respuesta como actualización de la publicación debido a le extensión.

Comment: gracias por la explicación extra.

Comment: como comenta dwanrandae , hay que diferenciar mucho entre arrays y slides, los primeros siempre les declaras la longitud, mientras que al slice se le crea de otra manera, por lo general siempre usas append para añadirle elementos al slice.
Aqui te dejo unas ligas donde muestran ejemplos de Arrays & Slices
**Array**: https://gobyexample.com/arrays
**Slice**: https://gobyexample.com/slices
Saludos